# Javascirpt: Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, html

I am unable to invoke a function on clicking a button. I ve looked at other questions and implemented what is present in those yet I am getting the error in the title. What am I doing wrong?

HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>TITLE</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/semantic.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/libs/jQuery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h1>HEADER</h1>
      <div>
        <button class="ui button primary" onclick="submitInput();">
            BUTTON
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/landing_page.js" async></script>
</html>
```

landing_page.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     window.onload = function(){
        function submitInput() {
            console.log("Submit");
        };
     }
});
```

Comment: move your function outside the onload event. You are using nesting events wrong

Comment: please put your "submitInput()" outside the onload

Comment: @AnirudhaGupta takes more than that

Comment: Learn about scope....

Comment: @epascarello sorry, I didn't see that $(document).ready, yes, it must be otherside both.

Comment: putting it out of onLoad() did not fix it. changed it `$(document).ready(function() {
 function submitInput() { console.log("Submit"); };
});` same error

Comment: @HankMcDonnel you must put it outside everything on global level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

landing_page.js

```
function submitInput() {
  console.log("Submit");
};
```

In your code `submitInput` is declared in `onload` callback and is not available in global scope.

If you want `submitInput` to be declared after document is loaded and still be available in global scope do:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  window.submitInput = function(){
    console.log("Submit");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The definition of your function is not accessible to the page.
Edit your .js file to be

```
function submitInput() {
   console.log("Submit");
};
```

i.e., remove these lines:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
         window.onload = function(){
```